How to create a transparent overlay view to monitor if the user put pointer to the top most?
I want to create a transparent overlay view which is global (not only works on my own application),   and should not prevent the interacts with the application behind it.
I tried to make a overlay view with a height of 1 pixel, and make it to the top most:
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
  1,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
  PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP

val windowManager = context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
windowManager.addView(this, this.params)
//...
//...
//
override fun onGenericMotionEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
  // resolve event
  return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event)
}

In this way, it can put the view to the top most, but it seems the onGenericMotionEvent can be triggered when the pointer is moving between the status bar and the navigation bar.
